# AS3 Calling a child's index during a for each

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, parent-child

I have a function that uses a mouse click event to create a child of a symbol at the mouse's coordinates. The instance is then pushed to an array.

I am now trying to make a new function that allows you to drag/drop a child when the mouse is within 10 pixels of it. When the child is dropped, I want it to rotate to face the next child in the array. I am currently communicating with each child in the array using a `for each` loop.

**The bit I'm having trouble with** is getting the index value of the child being dropped and setting it to a variable.

For reference, `ins_trailPoint` is the variable that creates the child and `tPoint` is the name of the array containing the children. `child` is the variable trying to acquire the index value of the dropped child.

```
function movePoint(Event:MouseEvent):void {
    for each (var ins_trailPoint in tPoint) {
        var child:int = event.target.parent.getChildIndex(event.target);
        var px:Number = mouseX - ins_trailPoint.x;
        var py:Number = mouseY - ins_trailPoint.y;
        var dist = Math.sqrt(px*px + py*py);

        if (dist<10) {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addPoint);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropPoint);
            ins_trailPoint.startDrag();

            function dropPoint(event:MouseEvent):void {
                ins_trailPoint.stopDrag();
                var dx:Number = tPoint[child+1].x - ins_trailPoint.x;
                var dy:Number = tPoint[child+1].y - ins_trailPoint.y;
                var radians:Number = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
                ins_trailPoint.rotation = radians * 180/Math.PI;
```

Comment: I've changed the indentation of your code, but it now looks strange because dropPoint() is defined within movePoint(). Is it what you want, or is there a missing part of code (curly braces are never closed)?

Comment: tPoint.indexOf(ins_trailPoint)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `movePoint()` is called `Event` with a capital letter, but you try tu use `event` in lower case.